# How to Render Webcam/Live video in WebGL without Library

Tags: webgl

I have been following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Animating_textures_in_WebGL) tutorial and it succesfully renders video on to a cube using webGL.

Is it possible for instead of using a video I would like to use a live feed from a webcam without using frameworks like Three.js?

The code below reads from the webcam into `HTMLVideoElement` how to convert it into texture so I can map it to my vertices in raw WebGL?

```
function setupVideo(url) {
  const video = document.createElement('video');

  var playing = false;
  var timeupdate = false;

  video.autoplay = true;
  video.muted = true;
  video.loop = true;

  // Waiting for these 2 events ensures
  // there is data in the video

  video.addEventListener('playing', function() {
     playing = true;
     checkReady();
  }, true);

  video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function() {
     timeupdate = true;
     checkReady();
  }, true);
  navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia);

var hasUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ? true : false;

console.log(hasUserMedia);

// Prefer camera resolution nearest to 1280x720.
var constraints = { audio: true, video: { width: 640, height: 360 } };

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
.then(function(mediaStream) {
  video.srcObject = mediaStream;
  video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
  };
})
.catch(function(err) { console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message); }); // always check for errors at the end.

  video.play();

  function checkReady() {
    if (playing && timeupdate) {
      copyVideo = true;
    }
  }

  return video;
}
```

Comment: https://dev.to/learosema/realtime-video-processing-with-webgl-5653#uploading-image-data-to-your-webglrenderingcontext